# clistctrl selection programmatically

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a clistctrl which shows multiple data for multiple system.only 1 item can be selected of different system.

Initially the clistctrl loads with first item selected from the control for different systems.

But when i am changing selection from by clicking a item on the grid after changing the data in the model and setting the selection it's not showing the selection as from my data structure. instead it's showing only the clicked row as selected.
Note :: My data structure has proper value and setting selection is executing properly. I am doing a deselect before selection.
Select Deselect method :

```
    void SelectRow(int index)
    {
     SetFocus();
     EnsureVisible(index, FALSE);
     SetItemState(index, LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED);
    }
    void DeselectRow(int index)
    {
     SetItemState(index, ~LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED);
    }
```

Afx message for on click :

```
void MDialog::OnSelectedItemChanged(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT*pResult)
{
UpdateData(FALSE);
NM_LISTVIEW* pNMListView = (NM_LISTVIEW*)pNMHDR;
switch (pNMListView->hdr.code)
{
case LVN_ITEMCHANGED:
{
    (pNMListView->uNewState & LVIS_SELECTED)
    if (!m_lockSelection && (pNMListView->uChanged & LVIF_STATE))
    {
        m_lockSelection = true;
        FINALLY([=] {
            m_lockSelection = false; 
        });
        m_allPositionsView.ViewModel().Update(ntype::selection, pNMListView->iItem);
    }
}
break;
}
UpdateData(TRUE);
}
```

Finally Notification event where i am selecting :

```
void MDialog::OnRefinedProgramViewModelNotify(const MyProject::abc::ntype& notifyId)
{  
  for (int i = 0; i < int(m_allPositionsView.ViewModel().Model().Count()); ++i)
    {
        if (m_allPositionsView.ViewModel().Model().At(i).IsSelectedPosition())
                    {
                        m_allPositionsView.SelectRow(i);
                    }
    }
}
```

The program is executing the selection method properly.

```
        m_allPositionsView.SelectRow(i);
```

But in view i only can see the clicked item selected. But there are other items i am expected to stay selected.

Why can't it just do the selection i am doing programmatically?

Comment: am giving this s a comment since I can't verify this, I think you need to do a `SetItemState(index, 0, LVIS_SELECTED)` to deselect a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unselect the `index` row use this code:

```
      UINT nState = GetItemState(index, LVIS_SELECTED);
      nState &= ~LVIS_SELECTED;
      SetItemState(index, nState, LVIS_SELECTED);
```

To select the `index` row use:

```
      SetItemState(index, LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED);
```

Comment: *"you do not have to use `LVIS_FOCUSED`, but I recommend using it, as it looks nicer that way"* - Nicer or not, it's wrong. Now you have two elements on a dialog that appear to be focused. `LVIS_FOCUSED` is really only useful to determine the item state when performing custom drawing.

Comment: Thanks @IInspectable for the comment. I have removed the LVIS_FOCUSED